# what are the limitations of wpf web browser control?

Tags: c#, .net, wpf, browser

What are the limitations of WPF web browser control? Is it good enough for a real-life browser implementation? And is it a fully managed implementation?

Answer (score 2):

The WPF WebBrowser control is just an interop layer hosting the IE ActiveX control.  It should be very robust, and usable for a real-life browser (since it's really IE).  It is not a managed implementation.

Its main limitations are due to the fact that it's using an HwndHost internally.  This means that it has the WPF/Native airspace issues, as well as some minor issues with event handling.

Answer (score 1):

It is good enough for Real-life use, and I agree with Reeds view on the matter.

Additionaly, If a person does not have certain IE files on their computer the control is rendered useless. Here are a few observed limitations I have found:

- I have found with the `WebBrowser` controls is it's hatred of IE6 on a computer whilst trying to perform JavaScript insertions within the control. (Very machine-specific though, so you could say lack of total compatibility?)
- The fact that you will need to actually reference the main assemblies of IE to get certain functionality, such as getting something more useful than a `HtmlElement`.
- The lack of support for some of its 2.0 counterparts functions, such as to Suppress Script Errors.
- Doesn't work nicely with the WPF layout system
- Again due to the fact that its a wrapper for IE, all the compatibility issues in things like CSS stay put, as well as most, if not all the IE issues that exist.

All in all, the control could be greatly improved, and to honest it would be fantastic to see the .NET team make a fully managed version of this component.

Cheers,

Kyle

Answer (score 0):

Adding to the answers by @Kyle and @Reed, below are my observations as limitations.

- We can't render PDF in this WebBrowser control.
- Underneath engine is IE. We can't replace IE engine with latest Microsoft Edge.